# Is there anyway to format this? The code already runs fine but the formatting will run if the value is too big

Tags: java, formatting, overriding, tostring

I know that I can just use printf to format it but printf is used to print. I want to use the formatting to store the data then call the data to print it outside the do while loop.

```
 @Override
    public String toString() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String enter = "", data = "";
        double totalCommission = 0.0;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();

        do {
            setTransaction();
            setSalesNum();
            setName();
            setAmount();
            setCommission();
            setRate();

            do {
                //prompt user to enter another
                System.out.println("Would you like to enter another? [Y/N]");
                boolean error = false;

                //error prompt if y or n is not entered 
                enter = input.next();

                if (!(enter.equals("n") || enter.equals("N") || enter.equals("y") || enter.equals("Y"))) {
                    error = true;
                    System.out.println("Invalid input! Please enter again.\n Would you like to enter another student's mark? [Y/N]");
                } else {
                    error = false;
                }

            } while (false);

            //setting the decimal places
            df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            //transaction details saved here
            data += getTransaction() + "\t" + getSalesNum() + "\t\t" + getName() + "\t\t" + (df.format(getAmount())) + "\t" + "     " + getRate() + "%" + "\t\t" + (df.format(getCompute())) + "\n";
            totalCommission = totalCommission + getCompute();

        } while (enter.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

        System.out.println("Sales\tCommission");
        System.out.println("TNO#\tSALESNO#\tNAME\t\tAMOUNT\t\t" + "  " + "COMM RATE\tCOMMISSION");

        return String.format(data + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + "  " + "TOTAL COMMISSION\t" + (df.format(totalCommission)));
    }
```

So what I wanted to do is for this part `data += getTransaction() + "\t" + getSalesNum() + "\t\t" + getName() + "\t\t" + (df.format(getAmount())) + "\t" + "     " + getRate() + "%" + "\t\t" + (df.format(getCompute())) + "\n";` to be formatted inside  `while (enter.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));` then send `data` here: `return String.format(data + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + "  " + "TOTAL COMMISSION\t" + (df.format(totalCommission)));`

Comment: The point of `String.format` is to use `%s` (etc.) placeholders, the same as you would with `printf`. If you know how to do it with `printf`, do that with `String.format`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I don't understand what you want to achieve. You may add an input and desired output example.

First of all:

```
if (!(enter.equals("n") || enter.equals("N") || enter.equals("y") || enter.equals("Y"))) {

if (!(enter.equalsIgnoreCase("n")|| enter.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))) {
```

You talked about print so you may want to take a look into: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format
Because you mentioned String.format already I guess I misunderstood your question. If you reply back to me I will try to help you.

You wrote that you want to store your data inside that while loop and return it later. In this case, I would add every data to a list and return this list.